# How to export type constructors when using DataKinds extension?

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds

Playing with advanced type-system stuff. I want to have named kind and a
couple of type constructors that produce types of that kind:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

data Subject = New | Existing
```

Here, as I understand, we have named kind `Subject` and type constructors
`New` and `Existing` that are `:: Subject`. These type constructors do not
take arguments (I plan to use them as phantom types), it should be roughly
equivalent to:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}

data New
data Existing
```

With the difference that now I can write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

-- …

data MyConfig :: Subject -> * -> * where
  MyConfig
    { mcOneThing :: Path t File
    } :: MyConfig k t
```

This even compiles. What is confusing is that declaration of data kinds is
indistinguishable from data type declarations, so this code seems to produce
data type `Subject` as well as named kind `Subject` (?) It would be clearer
for me it we could specify on which level do we declare things (kinds, and
then `New` and `Existing` are type constructors; or types, and then `New`
and `Existing` are value constructors for things of `Subject` type). I don't
get this design decision with “promote everything that seems to work”.

Now, my problem is that I cannot export `New` and `Existing` as
type-constructors to use in other module, e.g. to declare things like:

```
foo :: MyConfig New Dir -> …
```

where at the same time

```
foo :: MyConfig Int Dir -> …
```

should be ill-kinded and it should not compile.

Here is how I'm trying to export them:

```
module MyModule
  ( New
  , Existing
  -- …
  )
where
```

What I get:

> Not in scope type constructor or class ‘New’
>
> Not in scope type constructor or class ‘Existing’

GHC manual in
[section 7.9.3](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.3/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html#promotion-syntax)
says that to distinguish between “types and constructors” one can use single quote `'`, so I tried:

```
module MyModule
  ( 'New
  , 'Existing
  -- …
  )
where
```

…but now it's a parse error.

---

How do I export `New` and `Existing` type constructors, and most
importantly, is there anything wrong with my current understanding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the usual syntax for exporting constructors:

```
module MyModule (Subject(..)) where

data Subject = New | Existing
```

Currently, lifted and unlifted constructors are tied together, so we can only export/import them together.

Also, you don't need to have `DataKinds` in `MyModule`, only in the module where you intend to use lifted constructors.

Comment: In other words, promoted constructors are never exported – rather, the ordinary constructors are only promoted whereever you import them.